# Pinescript Strategy Entry/Exit Not executing where it should (but close?)

Tags: pine-script, strategy-pattern

I have a study I'm converting into a strategy. The study had provided alerts for indicators. They seem to work, however the entry and exits are not when the alerts are triggering. For instance in the photo where the yellow flags are, that's where the buys should be. Any ideas?

EDIT: Looks like the entries are triggering as soon as divergence occurs (which makes sense) however I want it to occur where the yellow flags drop. Any ideas on how to trigger entries on that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilvew.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2bM5.png)

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © LonesomeTheBlue

//@version=4
strategy("DM Strategy 2", overlay = true, max_bars_back = 1000, max_lines_count = 400, max_labels_count = 400)
prd = input(defval = 5, title = "Pivot Period", minval = 1, maxval = 50)
source = input(defval = "Close", title = "Source for Pivot Points", options = ["Close", "High/Low"])
searchdiv = input(defval = "Regular", title = "Divergence Type", options = ["Regular", "Hidden", "Regular/Hidden"])
showindis = input(defval = "Full", title = "Show Indicator Names", options = ["Full", "First Letter", "Don't Show"])
showlimit = input(1, title="Minimum Number of Divergence", minval = 1, maxval = 11)
maxpp = input(defval = 10, title = "Maximum Pivot Points to Check", minval = 1, maxval = 20)
maxbars = input(defval = 100, title = "Maximum Bars to Check", minval = 30, maxval = 200)
shownum = input(defval = true, title = "Show Divergence Number")
showlast = input(defval = false, title = "Show Only Last Divergence")
dontconfirm = input(defval = false, title = "Don't Wait for Confirmation")
showlines = input(defval = true, title = "Show Divergence Lines")
showpivot = input(defval = false, title = "Show Pivot Points")
calcmacd = input(defval = true, title = "MACD")
calcmacda = input(defval = true, title = "MACD Histogram")
calcrsi = input(defval = true, title = "RSI")
calcstoc = input(defval = true, title = "Stochastic")
calccci = input(defval = true, title = "CCI")
calcmom = input(defval = true, title = "Momentum")
calcobv = input(defval = true, title = "OBV")
calcvwmacd = input(true, title = "VWmacd")
calccmf = input(true, title = "Chaikin Money Flow")
calcmfi = input(true, title = "Money Flow Index")
calcext = input(false, title = "Check External Indicator")
externalindi = input(defval = close, title = "External Indicator")
pos_reg_div_col = input(defval = color.yellow, title = "Positive Regular Divergence")
neg_reg_div_col = input(defval = color.navy, title = "Negative Regular Divergence")
pos_hid_div_col = input(defval = color.lime, title = "Positive Hidden Divergence")
neg_hid_div_col = input(defval = color.red, title = "Negative Hidden Divergence")
pos_div_text_col = input(defval = color.black, title = "Positive Divergence Text Color")
neg_div_text_col = input(defval = color.white, title = "Negative Divergence Text Color")
reg_div_l_style_ = input(defval = "Solid", title = "Regular Divergence Line Style", options = ["Solid", "Dashed", "Dotted"])
hid_div_l_style_ = input(defval = "Dashed", title = "Hdden Divergence Line Style", options = ["Solid", "Dashed", "Dotted"])
reg_div_l_width = input(defval = 2, title = "Regular Divergence Line Width", minval = 1, maxval = 5)
hid_div_l_width = input(defval = 1, title = "Hidden Divergence Line Width", minval = 1, maxval = 5)
showmas = input(defval = false, title = "Show MAs 50 & 200", inline = "ma12")
cma1col = input(defval = color.lime, title = "", inline = "ma12")
cma2col = input(defval = color.red, title = "", inline = "ma12")

plot(showmas ? sma(close, 50) : na, color = showmas ? cma1col : na)
plot(showmas ? sma(close, 200) : na, color = showmas ? cma2col: na)

// set line styles
var reg_div_l_style = reg_div_l_style_ == "Solid" ? line.style_solid : 
                       reg_div_l_style_ == "Dashed" ? line.style_dashed :
                       line.style_dotted
var hid_div_l_style = hid_div_l_style_ == "Solid" ? line.style_solid : 
                       hid_div_l_style_ == "Dashed" ? line.style_dashed :
                       line.style_dotted


// get indicators
rsi = rsi(close, 14) // RSI
[macd, signal, deltamacd] = macd(close, 12, 26, 9) // MACD
moment = mom(close, 10) // Momentum
cci = cci(close, 10) // CCI
Obv = obv // OBV
stk = sma(stoch(close, high, low, 14), 3) // Stoch
maFast = vwma(close, 12), maSlow = vwma(close, 26), vwmacd = maFast - maSlow // volume weighted macd
Cmfm = ((close-low) - (high-close)) / (high - low), Cmfv = Cmfm * volume, cmf = sma(Cmfv, 21) / sma(volume,21) // Chaikin money flow
Mfi = mfi(close, 14) // Moneyt Flow Index

// keep indicators names and colors in arrays
var indicators_name = array.new_string(11)
var div_colors = array.new_color(4)
if barstate.isfirst
    // names
    array.set(indicators_name, 0, showindis == "Full" ? "MACD" : "M")
    array.set(indicators_name, 1, showindis == "Full" ? "Hist" : "H")
    array.set(indicators_name, 2, showindis == "Full" ? "RSI" : "E")
    array.set(indicators_name, 3, showindis == "Full" ? "Stoch" : "S")
    array.set(indicators_name, 4, showindis == "Full" ? "CCI" : "C")
    array.set(indicators_name, 5, showindis == "Full" ? "MOM" : "M")
    array.set(indicators_name, 6, showindis == "Full" ? "OBV" : "O")
    array.set(indicators_name, 7, showindis == "Full" ? "VWMACD" : "V")
    array.set(indicators_name, 8, showindis == "Full" ? "CMF" : "C")
    array.set(indicators_name, 9, showindis == "Full" ? "MFI" : "M")
    array.set(indicators_name,10, showindis == "Full" ? "Extrn" : "X")
    //colors
    array.set(div_colors, 0, pos_reg_div_col)
    array.set(div_colors, 1, neg_reg_div_col)
    array.set(div_colors, 2, pos_hid_div_col)
    array.set(div_colors, 3, neg_hid_div_col)

// Check if we get new Pivot High Or Pivot Low
float ph = pivothigh((source == "Close" ? close : high), prd, prd)
float pl = pivotlow((source == "Close" ? close : low), prd, prd)
plotshape(ph and showpivot, text = "H",  style = shape.labeldown, color = color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor = color.red, location = location.abovebar, offset = -prd)
plotshape(pl and showpivot, text = "L",  style = shape.labelup, color = color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor = color.lime, location = location.belowbar, offset = -prd)

// keep values and positions of Pivot Highs/Lows in the arrays
var int maxarraysize = 20
var ph_positions = array.new_int(maxarraysize, 0)
var pl_positions = array.new_int(maxarraysize, 0)
var ph_vals = array.new_float(maxarraysize, 0.)
var pl_vals = array.new_float(maxarraysize, 0.)

// add PHs to the array
if ph
    array.unshift(ph_positions, bar_index)
    array.unshift(ph_vals, ph)
    if array.size(ph_positions) > maxarraysize
        array.pop(ph_positions)
        array.pop(ph_vals)

// add PLs to the array
if pl
    array.unshift(pl_positions, bar_index)
    array.unshift(pl_vals, pl)
    if array.size(pl_positions) > maxarraysize
        array.pop(pl_positions)
        array.pop(pl_vals)

// functions to check Regular Divergences and Hidden Divergences

// function to check positive regular or negative hidden divergence
// cond == 1 => positive_regular, cond == 2=> negative_hidden
positive_regular_positive_hidden_divergence(src, cond)=>
    divlen = 0
    prsc = source == "Close" ? close : low
    // if indicators higher than last value and close price is higher than las close 
    if dontconfirm or src > src[1] or close > close[1]
        startpoint = dontconfirm ? 0 : 1 // don't check last candle
        // we search last 15 PPs
        for x = 0 to maxpp - 1
            len = bar_index - array.get(pl_positions, x) + prd
            // if we reach non valued array element or arrived 101. or previous bars then we don't search more
            if array.get(pl_positions, x) == 0 or len > maxbars
                break
            if len > 5 and 
               ((cond == 1 and src[startpoint] > src[len] and prsc[startpoint] < nz(array.get(pl_vals, x))) or
               (cond == 2 and src[startpoint] < src[len] and prsc[startpoint] > nz(array.get(pl_vals, x))))
                slope1 = (src[startpoint] - src[len]) / (len - startpoint)
                virtual_line1 = src[startpoint] - slope1
                slope2 = (close[startpoint] - close[len]) / (len - startpoint)
                virtual_line2 = close[startpoint] - slope2
                arrived = true
                for y = 1 + startpoint to len - 1
                    if src[y] < virtual_line1 or nz(close[y]) < virtual_line2
                        arrived := false
                        break
                    virtual_line1 := virtual_line1 - slope1
                    virtual_line2 := virtual_line2 - slope2
                
                if arrived
                    divlen := len
                    break
    divlen

// function to check negative regular or positive hidden divergence
// cond == 1 => negative_regular, cond == 2=> positive_hidden
negative_regular_negative_hidden_divergence(src, cond)=>
    divlen = 0
    prsc = source == "Close" ? close : high
    // if indicators higher than last value and close price is higher than las close 
    if dontconfirm or src < src[1] or close < close[1]
        startpoint = dontconfirm ? 0 : 1 // don't check last candle
        // we search last 15 PPs
        for x = 0 to maxpp - 1
            len = bar_index - array.get(ph_positions, x) + prd
            // if we reach non valued array element or arrived 101. or previous bars then we don't search more
            if array.get(ph_positions, x) == 0 or len > maxbars
                break
            if len > 5 and 
               ((cond == 1 and src[startpoint] < src[len] and prsc[startpoint] > nz(array.get(ph_vals, x))) or 
               (cond == 2 and src[startpoint] > src[len] and prsc[startpoint] < nz(array.get(ph_vals, x))))
                slope1 = (src[startpoint] - src[len]) / (len - startpoint)
                virtual_line1 = src[startpoint] - slope1
                slope2 = (close[startpoint] - nz(close[len])) / (len - startpoint)
                virtual_line2 = close[startpoint] - slope2
                arrived = true
                for y = 1 + startpoint to len - 1
                    if src[y] > virtual_line1 or nz(close[y]) > virtual_line2
                        arrived := false
                        break
                    virtual_line1 := virtual_line1 - slope1
                    virtual_line2 := virtual_line2 - slope2
                
                if arrived
                    divlen := len
                    break
    divlen

// calculate 4 types of divergence if enabled in the options and return divergences in an array
calculate_divs(cond, indicator)=>
    divs = array.new_int(4, 0)
    array.set(divs, 0, cond and (searchdiv == "Regular" or searchdiv == "Regular/Hidden") ? positive_regular_positive_hidden_divergence(indicator, 1) : 0)
    array.set(divs, 1, cond and (searchdiv == "Regular" or searchdiv == "Regular/Hidden") ? negative_regular_negative_hidden_divergence(indicator, 1) : 0)
    array.set(divs, 2, cond and (searchdiv == "Hidden" or searchdiv == "Regular/Hidden")  ? positive_regular_positive_hidden_divergence(indicator, 2) : 0)
    array.set(divs, 3, cond and (searchdiv == "Hidden" or searchdiv == "Regular/Hidden")  ? negative_regular_negative_hidden_divergence(indicator, 2) : 0)
    divs

// array to keep all divergences
var all_divergences = array.new_int(44) // 11 indicators * 4 divergence = 44 elements
// set related array elements
array_set_divs(div_pointer, index)=>
    for x = 0 to 3
        array.set(all_divergences, index * 4 + x, array.get(div_pointer, x))

// set divergences array 
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcmacd, macd), 0)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcmacda, deltamacd), 1)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcrsi, rsi), 2)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcstoc, stk), 3)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calccci, cci), 4)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcmom, moment), 5)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcobv, Obv), 6)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcvwmacd, vwmacd), 7)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calccmf, cmf), 8)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcmfi, Mfi), 9)
array_set_divs(calculate_divs(calcext, externalindi), 10)

// check minimum number of divergence, if less than showlimit then delete all divergence
total_div = 0
for x = 0 to array.size(all_divergences) - 1
    total_div := total_div + round(sign(array.get(all_divergences, x)))

if total_div < showlimit
    array.fill(all_divergences, 0)

// keep line in an array
var pos_div_lines = array.new_line(0)
var neg_div_lines = array.new_line(0)
var pos_div_labels = array.new_label(0)
var neg_div_labels = array.new_label(0) 

// remove old lines and labels if showlast option is enabled
delete_old_pos_div_lines()=>
    if array.size(pos_div_lines) > 0    
        for j = 0 to array.size(pos_div_lines) - 1 
            line.delete(array.get(pos_div_lines, j))
        array.clear(pos_div_lines)

delete_old_neg_div_lines()=>
    if array.size(neg_div_lines) > 0    
        for j = 0 to array.size(neg_div_lines) - 1 
            line.delete(array.get(neg_div_lines, j))
        array.clear(neg_div_lines)

delete_old_pos_div_labels()=>
    if array.size(pos_div_labels) > 0 
        for j = 0 to array.size(pos_div_labels) - 1 
            label.delete(array.get(pos_div_labels, j))
        array.clear(pos_div_labels)

delete_old_neg_div_labels()=>
    if array.size(neg_div_labels) > 0    
        for j = 0 to array.size(neg_div_labels) - 1 
            label.delete(array.get(neg_div_labels, j))
        array.clear(neg_div_labels)

// delete last creted lines and labels until we met new PH/PV 
delete_last_pos_div_lines_label(n)=>
    if n > 0 and array.size(pos_div_lines) >= n    
        asz = array.size(pos_div_lines)
        for j = 1 to n
            line.delete(array.get(pos_div_lines, asz - j))
            array.pop(pos_div_lines)
        if array.size(pos_div_labels) > 0  
            label.delete(array.get(pos_div_labels, array.size(pos_div_labels) - 1))
            array.pop(pos_div_labels)

delete_last_neg_div_lines_label(n)=>
    if n > 0 and array.size(neg_div_lines) >= n    
        asz = array.size(neg_div_lines)
        for j = 1 to n
            line.delete(array.get(neg_div_lines, asz - j))
            array.pop(neg_div_lines)
        if array.size(neg_div_labels) > 0  
            label.delete(array.get(neg_div_labels, array.size(neg_div_labels) - 1))
            array.pop(neg_div_labels)
            
// variables for Alerts
pos_reg_div_detected = false
neg_reg_div_detected = false
pos_hid_div_detected = false
neg_hid_div_detected = false

// to remove lines/labels until we met new // PH/PL
var last_pos_div_lines = 0
var last_neg_div_lines = 0
var remove_last_pos_divs = false 
var remove_last_neg_divs = false
if pl
    remove_last_pos_divs := false
    last_pos_div_lines := 0
if ph
    remove_last_neg_divs := false
    last_neg_div_lines := 0

// draw divergences lines and labels
divergence_text_top = ""
divergence_text_bottom = ""
distances = array.new_int(0)
dnumdiv_top = 0
dnumdiv_bottom = 0
top_label_col = color.white
bottom_label_col = color.white
old_pos_divs_can_be_removed = true
old_neg_divs_can_be_removed = true
startpoint = dontconfirm ? 0 : 1 // used for don't confirm option

for x = 0 to 10
    div_type = -1
    for y = 0 to 3
        if array.get(all_divergences, x * 4 + y) > 0 // any divergence?
            div_type := y
            if (y % 2) == 1 
                dnumdiv_top := dnumdiv_top + 1
                top_label_col := array.get(div_colors, y)
            if (y % 2) == 0
                dnumdiv_bottom := dnumdiv_bottom + 1
                bottom_label_col := array.get(div_colors, y)
            if not array.includes(distances, array.get(all_divergences, x * 4 + y))  // line not exist ?
                array.push(distances, array.get(all_divergences, x * 4 + y))
                new_line = showlines ? line.new(x1 = bar_index - array.get(all_divergences, x * 4 + y), 
                          y1 = (source == "Close" ? close[array.get(all_divergences, x * 4 + y)] : 
                                           (y % 2) == 0 ? low[array.get(all_divergences, x * 4 + y)] : 
                                                          high[array.get(all_divergences, x * 4 + y)]),
                          x2 = bar_index - startpoint,
                          y2 = (source == "Close" ? close[startpoint] : 
                                           (y % 2) == 0 ? low[startpoint] : 
                                                          high[startpoint]),
                          color = array.get(div_colors, y),
                          style = y < 2 ? reg_div_l_style : hid_div_l_style,
                          width = y < 2 ? reg_div_l_width : hid_div_l_width
                          )
                          : na
                if (y % 2) == 0
                    if old_pos_divs_can_be_removed
                        old_pos_divs_can_be_removed := false
                        if not showlast and remove_last_pos_divs
                            delete_last_pos_div_lines_label(last_pos_div_lines)
                            last_pos_div_lines := 0
                        if showlast
                            delete_old_pos_div_lines()
                    array.push(pos_div_lines, new_line)
                    last_pos_div_lines := last_pos_div_lines + 1
                    remove_last_pos_divs := true
                    
                if (y % 2) == 1
                    if old_neg_divs_can_be_removed
                        old_neg_divs_can_be_removed := false
                        if not showlast and remove_last_neg_divs
                            delete_last_neg_div_lines_label(last_neg_div_lines)
                            last_neg_div_lines := 0
                        if showlast
                            delete_old_neg_div_lines()
                    array.push(neg_div_lines, new_line)
                    last_neg_div_lines := last_neg_div_lines + 1
                    remove_last_neg_divs := true
                    
            // set variables for alerts
            if y == 0
                pos_reg_div_detected := true
            if y == 1
                neg_reg_div_detected := true
            if y == 2
                pos_hid_div_detected := true
            if y == 3
                neg_hid_div_detected := true
    // get text for labels
    if div_type >= 0
        divergence_text_top    := divergence_text_top    + ((div_type % 2) == 1 ? (showindis != "Don't Show" ? array.get(indicators_name, x) + "\n" : "") : "")
        divergence_text_bottom := divergence_text_bottom + ((div_type % 2) == 0 ? (showindis != "Don't Show" ? array.get(indicators_name, x) + "\n" : "") : "")


// draw labels
if showindis != "Don't Show" or shownum
    if shownum and dnumdiv_top > 0
        divergence_text_top := divergence_text_top + tostring(dnumdiv_top)
    if shownum and dnumdiv_bottom > 0
        divergence_text_bottom := divergence_text_bottom + tostring(dnumdiv_bottom)
    if divergence_text_top != ""
        if showlast
            delete_old_neg_div_labels()
        array.push(neg_div_labels, 
                      label.new( x = bar_index, 
                                 y = max(high, high[1]), 
                                 text = divergence_text_top,
                                 color = top_label_col,
                                 textcolor = neg_div_text_col,
                                 style = label.style_label_down
                                 ))
                                 
    if divergence_text_bottom != ""
        if showlast
            delete_old_pos_div_labels()
        array.push(pos_div_labels, 
                      label.new( x = bar_index, 
                                 y = min(low, low[1]), 
                                 text = divergence_text_bottom,
                                 color = bottom_label_col, 
                                 textcolor = pos_div_text_col,
                                 style = label.style_label_up
                                 ))
                                 
    
alertcondition(pos_reg_div_detected, title='Positive Regular Divergence Detected', message='Positive Regular Divergence Detected')
alertcondition(neg_reg_div_detected, title='Negative Regular Divergence Detected', message='Negative Regular Divergence Detected')
alertcondition(pos_hid_div_detected, title='Positive Hidden Divergence Detected', message='Positive Hidden Divergence Detected')
alertcondition(neg_hid_div_detected, title='Negative Hidden Divergence Detected', message='Negative Hidden Divergence Detected')

alertcondition(pos_reg_div_detected or pos_hid_div_detected, title='Positive Divergence Detected', message='Positive Divergence Detected')
alertcondition(neg_reg_div_detected or neg_hid_div_detected, title='Negative Divergence Detected', message='Negative Divergence Detected')

buySignal   = pos_reg_div_detected or pos_hid_div_detected
sellSignal  = neg_reg_div_detected or neg_hid_div_detected

// Submit entry orders
if (buySignal)
    strategy.entry(id="EL", long=true)

// Submit exit orders
strategy.close_all(when=sellSignal)
```

Comment: I wonder if this has something to do with Pyramiding?

Comment: Okay, so basically I need my strategy.entry to execute when the yellow label occurs.

Comment: Figured out a solution, wild, but I got it! :)

Comment: jeff, you did? what's your solution?